# Best practices to use web hosting space with Node.js app?

Tags: node.js, heroku, upload

I am creating a Node.js app that runs on Heroku. The app will allow the user to upload and store some files.

My problem is that, since the app is running on Heroku, the file will be uploaded and stored where the app lays and that is by no means a good solution (the files will be removed at the next deploy and Heroku is not meant to store files).

What are the best practice to upload and store the file into the hosting space given by my domain provider?

Comment: The best practice is *not* to store data in the hosting space, put it in a DB or file store: https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted.

Answer (score 0):

When using Heroku, (and any other platform, really), the best practice is to use a file storage If you're saving files, and a database if you're saving regular data.

There are plenty to choose from. The most common ones are:

- Amazon S3 Bucket https://aws.amazon.com/s3/
- Google Storage Bucket https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets

The absolute easiest way to deal with both file storage and database, is to use Google Firebase. 
Firebase is a Google product, which includes everything you need to build an app, except the front end. Since you're working on a Node app you are able to use parts of firebase to suit your needs. You can read more at [www.firebase.com](http://www.firebase.com)